# htaccess преобразование url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mvc

Сайт отправляет из формы методом GET данные

> http://myweb.com/product/?season=1&price=350%3B7700&page=1

Как сделать чтобы отправлял

> http://myweb.com/product/season/1/price350%7700/page/1

Я так понял через htaccess, но, к сожалению, нет опыта работы с директивами апача, кто знает скажите куда копать или как сделать!

Еще есть безумная идея обрабатывать строку GET методом класса и делать редирект, но думаю, проще, конечно, с помощью htaccess. Просто нужно очень или скажите куда копать!

Answer (score 1):

я не очень понял вашу формулировку :(, но преобразование, которое указано в вопросе, можно сделать следующим образом

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  season=(\d+)&price=(\d+)%3B(\d+)&page=(\d+)
RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ $1season/%1/price%2%%3/page/%4?
```

Comment: Спасибо, давайте я поясню, значит у меня магазин,  mvc работает так что mysite.com/controleer/method/param1/param2/param3         метод принимает параметры массивом (array(param1,param2,param3)) и т.д.  так вот когда в форме поиска товара выбирают параметры и кликают  найти то происходит переход   http://myweb.com/product/?season=1&price=350%3B7700&page=1 а мне надо чтобы переход был на http://myweb.com/product/season/1/price350%7700/page/1 чтобы принять эти параметры и обработать их методом  или я что то не правильно понимаю что касается обработки запоросов.?!

Comment: то что я написал, это и должно делать. не получается?

Comment: Почему то нет,   вот содержание htaccess может что то не так                                                                 AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  season=(\d+)&price=(\d+)%3B(\d+)&page=(\d+)
RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ $1season/%1/price%2%%3/page/%4?

Comment: поставьте две последних моих строки после RewriteBase

Comment: Поставил,  при клике найти переходит на 
http://cmvc.com/product/?season=3&price=350%3B7700&page=1,  

код формы  

<form id="formFilter" method="get" action="/product/" > 
<input type="text" name="season" value="1">
<input type="text"  name="price" value="350%3B7700">
<input type="text"  name="page" value="1">
<input type="submit"  name="send" value="send">

</form>

Comment: сходил на тестер http://htaccess.mwl.be/ попробовал, работает. Видимо, я что-то упускаю, но не могу понять, что :(

Comment: Видимо я сам где-то туплю)) Тем не менее спасибо что пытаетесь помочь))

Comment: На этом же сайте сейчас проверял если код то все работает

AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  season=(\d+)&price=(\d+)%3B(\d+)&page=(\d+)
RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ $1season/%1/price%2%%3/page/%4?


Если такой то нет 

AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  season=(\d+)&price=(\d+)%3B(\d+)&page=(\d+)
RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ $1season/%1/price%2%%3/page/%4?

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php